# Maven: create directory structure from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have Maven a pom.xml file (copied from another project, and adapted), and I would like to generate the directory structure for a new project. Which command can do this?

Note that I found countless examples on the web, that explained how to use **mvn archetype:create** to create a pom.xml file and the directory structure, but I already have a pom.xml, and I would like to create the directories based on that, without specifying groupId, artifactId etc on the command line.

**mvn archetype:create-from-project** also seems to create a pom.xml based on another pom.xml (?) but I just want the directories. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I am aware that this is not a "big problem" because I can create the directories manually :) I did it already many times, and I always felt that there must be a *smarter* way to do it...

Comment: I use an IDE to build the project structure. It generates the maven poml. from a template and the directories required. It also sets the parent pom when adding modules.

Comment: I use Idea, and after "New Project" I select import from Maven. This set up the pom.xml and the libraries, but did not create the maven-speciofic directory structure.

Comment: It only creates the directories if you use it to create the pom.xml as well.

Comment: Yes, if I use Idea to create a new project with a "maven module", then it creates the directories, but then I have to specify the groupId, artifactId myself (and copy manually all the dependencies and settings), so this is not easier than mvn archetype:create.

Comment: I would use the archetype in IntelliJ when I build the project/module so I don't see how using `archetype:create` externally is any different.

Comment: The problem is that it is not different... Creating archetypes seems overkill to me... I would like more than a solution, I would like a simple solution :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not to sound condescending, but:

```
mkdir -p src/main/java
mkdir -p src/main/resources
mkdir -p src/test/java
mkdir -p src/test/resources
```

(or feel free to substitute different directories).

I don't know of any maven command that will create this structure for you without creating a new pom file.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this solution (actually I did it already too many times) but could not believe that there is no maven-supported way... Suppose some non-standard directories are configured in pom.xml... Anyway, if there will be no better answers, I will accept this one :)

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it seems that there is no better one.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: everyone will have to run the same four commands or create a script to do it ... when the whole point of maven is to automate the build process/project structure.

Comment: This manual solution works only if you use the standard directory structure.

Comment: Remember, the maven folks "love" convention.  If you're not following it, it makes your life more difficult.  If you want this functionality, it should be relatively easy to write a mojo (ie. you're own plugin) to do this for you.  I just have never done it, because i use the standard directory structure 99% of the time.

Comment: Or the following mkdir:
    mkdir -p src/{main,test}/{java,resources}

Comment: @HankCa great, thanks for the hack (never looked at shell doc .. )

Comment: Yes *nix is great.  Can't stand that so many places insist you use Windows.

Comment: As a final comment, I use gradle where possible these days.  In a (Java) project you can run the following and it will create the required directories and a template gradle.build file - `gradle init --type java-library`.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Matt not going to lie, I needed this stackoverflow answer as I was too lazy to write those 4 lines of code :D

Comment: missing a bunch of stuff my friend. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: What is `-p` for?

Answer (score 20):

I agree that there *should* be a way to specify that maven itself should look at my pom and generate a project/dir structure from that.  I don't know of a way to do that, but here's what I do:

**Step 1**: move your already created pom.xml somewhere else (maven will complain if you already have it in the directory where you will run the next command)

**Step 2**: from the command line, in your new maven project directory execute:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example.mypackage -DartifactId=myartifact
```

You do have to edit groupId and artifactId to match your pom (sigh), but this creates the basic directory structure for you and a default Java class and Unit test.

**Step 3**: move/copy your pom.xml into that project directory

**Step 4**: run some maven command like `mvn clean package` or `mvn dependency:tree` to start downloading dependencies

*Note:* I'm including this answer because some of the previous answers recommend using `mvn archetype:create`, but according to the maven website [that goal is deprecated](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-mojo.html) in favor of using `generate`.  And I wanted to show how to do it independent of any IDE or IDE plugins.

Comment: +1 for a soul mate who thinks that maven should be able to do this if it has all the necessary information :) However this solution is not simpler than creating/using a small batch script, which I did at the end...

Comment: @lbalazscs +1 also, I think this is lame too. I have a pom, I want it to create everything from scratch without an tricks (such as a batch file, good idea btw)

Comment: how do I do it without the `test` directory and using `junit` as a dependency?

Comment: scaffolding workflows are so time consuming, thank you questioneer & @quux00

Comment: This answer is broken due to a small problem: Package name "my.package.path" contains the system keyword "package" in auto-generated App.java (a dummy hello-world app). Error hit: "error: class, interface, or enum expected". Please update the package name to something like `-DgroupId=com.example.mypackage` which works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me like you are making a big problem out of a little one.

I'd try using `mvn archetype:create-from-project` ... and then just replace the generated POM file with the original one.

And as Peter Lawrey suggests, a lot of modern IDEs are capable of creating a Maven project structure.

Comment: Oh no, mvn archetype:create-from-project is a multi-step process in itself (see http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html), with a lot of directory-changing, copy, multiple maven commands. It semes to me that even creating directories manually is easier than that...

Comment: What about `mvn archetype:create` and replace the POM file then?  Or just use `mkdir`?  Or writing a simple shell script that does a sequence of `mkdir`s?

Comment: Basically I am looking for something that is easier than manually creating directories. I just couldn't believe that there is no automated way.

Comment: the whole point of maven is too have standardized project structure and build process. Its great in general, but I think it should also be able to create the directory strcutre from an existing pom

Comment: @NimChimpsky - Feel free to work out how to do it and contribute the code to the Maven project ...

Comment: Writing a tiny Maven plugin which can handle this problem is not a big task. You do not have to deal with complicated stuff as depedencies or similar stuff. You only have to read the project properties and to execute some mkdir commands.

Answer (score 2):

Analog to Matt's answer these lines will create the default maven folder structure on Microsoft Windows OS. Run them from the directory where your pom.xml exists:

```
mkdir -p src/main/java
mkdir -p src/main/resources
mkdir -p src/test/java
mkdir -p src/test/resources
```

I wonder why there is no maven command for this. You can either run the mkdir commands above, or use an archetype instead i.e. quickstart. There is the folder structure already in the box.

Comment: -p is not necessary for the windows command, in fact it creates a directory called "-p".

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by many answers from above, I find this to be the quickest

```sh
mkdir -p src/{main,test}/{java,resources}
```

which will generate the following structure

```sh
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   └── resources
    └── test
        ├── java
        └── resources
```

Note how by passing the sub-directory names in curly braces, you generate more than 1 sub-directory. E.g. `mkdir -p src/{dir1,dir2,dir3}` will give you this:

```sh
.
└── src
    ├── dir1
    ├── dir2
    └── dir3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Maven Build Helper plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/). Usage is pretty straightforward. Just configure in the plugins section of your pom, and call the appropriate mvn goal(s).

From the documentation:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-source</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>some directory</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This seems to be something different. This it is used "to add more source directories to your project, since pom.xml only allows one source directory." I asked for a way to automatically create the directories without changing the pom.xml. I didn't ask for extra source directories.

Comment: build-helper-maven-plugin doesn't create new folders. It add only folders to your build context.

Answer (score 0):

Maven can  generate it for you using the quickstart archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=com.mydomain \
    -DartifactId=my-project \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart
```

Then, copy and paste your existing pom.xml into the same directory as the pom.xml that was generated.

Comment: This generates the "quickstart" directories, but not based on the existing pom.xml - in fact it fails if already there is a pom.xml.

Comment: ok, I'll add a step to copy and paste your existing pom into the same directory as the pom that was generated

Answer (score 0):

Open command line, change directory to the folder with the pom.xml
and past this into the CMD:

```
echo This will create all required folders for maven project.
echo creating  Application\Library sources
MD "src\main\java"
echo creating  Application\Library resources
MD "src\main\resources"
echo creating  Resource filter files
MD "src\main\filters"
echo creating  Web application sources
MD "src\main\webapp"
echo creating  Test sources
MD "src\test\java"
echo creating  Test resources
MD "src\test\resources"
echo creating  Test resource filter files
MD "src\test\filters"
echo creating  Integration Tests (primarily for plugins)
MD "src\it"
echo creating  Assembly descriptors
MD "src\assembly"
echo creating  Site
MD "src\site"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one-liner:

```
touch pom.xml && mkdir -p src/main/java && mkdir -p src/main/resources && mkdir -p src/test/java && mkdir -p src/test/resources
```

It creates also an empty pom.xml. For quick access I've put it in my notes. Beside that it is similar @Matt answer.